# Creating procedure to validate data to be inserted

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure to prevent the insertion of an incorrect date. The table accepts an integer 8 digits long so `April 28 2015` would be inserted as `4282015`.

My logic here was to create some temp variables to store `month`, `date`, and `year` and then assign them values by taking sub strings from the original 8 digit value. I would then convert them to strings and concatenate together (I am not sure if there's a way to concatenate `int`, if there is that would probably be better) then convert that back to and `int` to be inserted. This is what I have tried so far.

UPDATE: The "sample" table is just an example, I will be running this on a different table in a poorly set up database (my job to run analysis and fix it up a little). The way they have it set up, date is an integer.

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
                id INT not null, 
                date INT not null
);


CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDate ( date int(8))
BEGIN
    DECLARE month INT;
    DECLARE day INT;
    DECLARE year INT;
    SET month = SUBSTRING(new.date, 1, 2);
    SET day = SUBSTRING(new.date, 3, 2);
    SET year = SUBSTRING(new.date, 5, 4);

    IF ( month IN(1, 12) AND day IN(1, 31) AND year IN(2012, 2013) )
        Declare temp as int;
        #Cast all variables as VARCHARS to concatenate together
        #Convert back to INT to be inserted
        Set temp =  CAST( (CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)) +
                CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
                CAST(year as VARCHAR(4))) as INT );
        insert into sample (id, date) values (1 ,temp);
    END IF;
END;
```

If anyone wants to take a look and give me some pointers or explain some stuff, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could create another procedure with parameters and run this in IF statement. That will be simplest to you.

Comment: why you are not using date or datetime or timestamp datatype to store that date ?

Comment: mysql <> sql server, please tag appropriate products only

Answer (score 3):

If you do the sensible thing, you will create the column as a Date or DateTime type. Since you have both MySQL and SQL-Server tags I don't actually know which DBMS you are using, but both of them support Date types.

Don't make it more complicated than you need to.

Comment: If it were up to me I would have created my tables with the DateTime type but unfortunately I did not set it up and its not my database. So unfortunately I have to work around their terms. The DBMS I'm working with is MySql adding the SQL-Server tag was a mistake, sorry!!